# Disable a php code only in homepage

Tags: php

I want to add a php code in my CMS site's header, but dont want to run it in homepage. Because it causes errors!!

already tried this code, but it somehow still runs the code and shows error

```
    <?php
$homepage = "/";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($homepage==$currentpage) {
}
else
{CODE}
?>
```

It is not an error, if the php code run in the home page header , it will call for a database query, which the home page is not assigned to work for. I am trying to add an additional feature.

[Error page](http://nextinweb.com/coupon/index.php)

this is the code

```
<?php 



$item = the_item();
$imgsd = 'store_avatar( ( !empty( $item->image2 ) ? $item->image2 : store_avatar( $item->store_img ) ) )';

?>
```

Comment: and what is the error exactly that you're getting?

Comment: this is bad approach better repair the errors, and you can disable php on server's configuration

Comment: @Robert , that is not an error, if the php code run in the home page header , it will call for a database query, which the home page is not assigned to work for. I am trying to add an additional feature.

Comment: @ShijilT you could test some other variable other then the URL like session or cookies maybe?

Comment: @JamilHneini Hneini , I am  still learning many php basics. not an expert to sessions and cookies.... :-(

Comment: Do some basic debugging, echo both variables ( `$homepage / $currentpage` ) and see if they match, if they don't then there you go.

Comment: Please take a note, that call for DB from html it is not a good approach. You should avoid this at all.

Comment: @ShijilT do you enclose all brackets right?

Comment: why did you want us to fetch the error message from  your site? `Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_item()...` that should have been placed in your question. The error is obvious here. If the function doesn't exist, you need to create it. If it exists, then included files may have failed you; check your paths. You failed to give us the full codes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this (might work):

```
<?php
    $homepage = array("/","/index.html","/index.php");
    $currentpage = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(!in_array($currentpage, $homepage)) {    
        //Code goes here
    }
?>
```

P.S. : Try to ALWAYS indent your code especially when you post on the internet.

Comment: it didnt work  `code`<?php
    $homepage = array("/","/index.html","/index.php");
    $currentpage = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(!in_array($currentpage, $homepage)) {    
       $item = the_item();
$imgsd = 'store_avatar( ( !empty( $item->image2 ) ? $item->image2 : store_avatar( $item->store_img ) ) )';

    }
?>`code`

Comment: @ShijilT are you sure the link is [host name]/index ? maybe it is [hostname]/something/index

Comment: Yes , you are right , it worked!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right - it's not the main page. Because your paste error from different page.

```
<?php
   $search_page = "/coupon/index.php";
   $current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if ($search_page !== $current_page) {
      // code
   }
?>
```

If it not helps, then:

1. Read comment Epodax
2. Read comment Fred

They wrote the answers for your question.

And please when you post a question at Stackoverflow you should clearly describe the question.

Comment: YES , that was the issue.